# cannot use pipeline in `intersect()` in R with dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

#### Context

I want to use `intersect()` with two character vectors, and I can do this straightway using `intersect(names(mtcars), a)`. But when I used pipeline an error occured.

#### Question

How can I use pipeline in `intersect()` in R with dplyr package.

#### Reproducible code

```
library(tidyverse)

a = c('mpg', 'cyl')

intersect(names(mtcars), a) # run correctly

mtcars %>% intersect(x = names(.), y = a) # error occur
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: How about `mtcars %>% names %>% intersect(a)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [`magrittr` readme:](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/)

> ### Re-using the placeholder for attributes
>
> It is straightforward to use the placeholder several times in a right-hand side expression. However, when the placeholder only appears in a nested expressions `magrittr` will still apply the first-argument rule. The reason is that in most cases this results more clean code.
>
> `x %>% f(y = nrow(.), z = ncol(.))` is equivalent to `f(x, y = nrow(x), z = ncol(x))`
>
> The behavior can be overruled by enclosing the right-hand side in braces:
>
> `x %>% {f(y = nrow(.), z = ncol(.))}` is equivalent to `f(y = nrow(x), z = ncol(x))`

So you have two options:

```
# straightforward
mtcars %>% names() %>% intersect(a)

# using the documented "overrule"
mtcars %>% {intersect(x = names(.), y = a)}
```